# What to name my ruby gem: Sqlite3Hash or Sqlite3::SomethingHash

Tags: ruby, hash, sqlite

I've written a gem that provides an SQLite3 backed Hash.

Originally I was going to name it SQLite3Hash, but then I realized that it might make sense to put it in the SQLite3 namespace.  Unfortunately that means I can't name it SQLite3::Hash because that means that anything in SQLite3 that needs a Hash will use my Hash instead.

So I could name it something like SQLite3::SQLite3Hash, but that seems unnecessarily verbose and repetitive.

Thoughts?

Comment: How about a comment for the downvote?  I won't revenge-vote, I actually want to know what's wrong with asking a question about naming conventions.

Comment: It seems to me that an internal implementation detail (which database to use) shouldn't affect the namespace of your code. I think this is a subjective topic though. (Upvoted to counter the downvote by someone else :))

Comment: A fun read:  http://www.slideshare.net/pirhilton/how-to-name-things-the-hardest-problem-in-programming

Comment: And not to rain on your parade (as I have not seen your code), but if you access SQLite3 with Jeremy Evan's Sequel gem, you can insert with hashes (or arrays of hashes), and selecting rows out results in an array of hash.

Comment: @JLB - I am aware of that, but I need a class that acts like a Hash with all of it's corresponding methods, not something that can get hashes and insert hashes from SQLite3.  :)

Comment: Interesting idea.  How about Olio as a name?  It's short, easy to remember, and is a synonym for hash.  http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/olio

Comment: That's a cute idea, but as it is basically a hash on the surface with minor changes, I don't know if coming up with a totally different name is needed - I want it to be really clear from the name as to what it is - it's only going to be used by people looking for something specific such as this.

Comment: I think at this point it probably makes sense to just go with SQLite3_Hash to avoid any namespace issue with SQLite3

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I have a good name for you, but I wouldn't namespace it under Sqlite3. Feels a bit invasive to that gem don't you think? :shrug:

P.S. HashQLite3 :)

Comment: Fair enough - I am less familiar with the Ruby gems community, but I am under the impression that in other communities it is generally considered better to keep things organized - but this is certainly a good example of how it raises namespace issues.